# How can i append my expressions in edit text all digits and signs?

Tags: android

Here is my java code, I want to append all expressions then starts the calculation. I need to see what I entered unless I press the equal sign. When I press that one I need to start the computation and see the correct answer of the input.

```
public class Calculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String res, res_plus, res_minus, res_times, res_divide;
Integer  wswitch;
Double answer = 0.0;
EditText result;
Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, plus, minus, times, divide, clear, equals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
    initializeVars();
}

public void initializeVars(){
    result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_result);
    one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
    two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
    three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
    four = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_four);
    five = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_five);
    six = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_six);
    seven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_seven);
    eight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_eight);
    nine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_nine);
    zero = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_zero);
    plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
    times = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_times);
    divide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_divide);
    equals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_equals);
    clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);

    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    four.setOnClickListener(this);
    five.setOnClickListener(this);
    six.setOnClickListener(this);
    seven.setOnClickListener(this);
    eight.setOnClickListener(this);
    nine.setOnClickListener(this);
    zero.setOnClickListener(this);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    times.setOnClickListener(this);
    divide.setOnClickListener(this);
    equals.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_one:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"1";
            result.setText(res);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_two:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"2";
            result.setText(res);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_three:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"3";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_four:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"4";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_five:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"5";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_six:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"6";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_seven:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"7";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_eight:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"8";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_nine:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"9";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_zero:
            res = result.getText().toString()+"0";
            result.setText(res);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_plus:

            res_plus = result.getText().toString();
            result.setText("");
            wswitch = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_minus:
            res_minus = result.getText().toString();
            result.setText("");
            wswitch = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_times:
            res_times = result.getText().toString();
            result.setText("");
            wswitch = 3;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_divide:
            res_divide = result.getText().toString();
            result.setText("");
            wswitch = 4;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_equals:
            switch(wswitch){
                case 1:
                    if(res_plus.matches("") || result.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        result.setText("");
                    }else{
                        answer = Double.parseDouble(res_plus)+Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
                        res = Double.toString(answer);
                        result.setText(res);

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(res_minus.matches("") || result.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        result.setText("");
                    }else{
                        answer = Double.parseDouble(res_minus)-Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
                        res = Double.toString(answer);
                        result.setText(res);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if(res_times.matches("") || result.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        result.setText("");
                    }else{
                        answer = Double.parseDouble(res_times)*Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
                        res = Double.toString(answer);
                        result.setText(res);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if(res_divide.matches("") || result.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        result.setText("");
                    }else{
                        answer = Double.parseDouble(res_divide)/Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
                        res = Double.toString(answer);
                        result.setText(res);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_clear:
            result.setText("");
            break;
    }
}
```

}